# Splitting up a Python dataframe based on column value and then using them in algorithm

Tags: python, pandas, apriori

I'm currently doing a simple frequent pattern analysis using the **Apriori** algorithm from **mlxtend**. Currently, I'm just looking at all transactions. But I'd like to differentiate the analysis based on country. My current script looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import pyodbc
from mlxtend.preprocessing import TransactionEncoder
from mlxtend.frequent_patterns import apriori
from mlxtend.frequent_patterns import association_rules

dataset = pd.read_sql_query("""some query"", cnxn)

# Transform/prep dataset into list data
dataset_tx = dataset.groupby(['ReceiptCode'])['ItemCategoryName'].apply(list).values.tolist()

# Define classifier
te = TransactionEncoder()

# Binary-transform dataset
te_ary = te.fit(dataset_tx).transform(dataset_tx)

# Fit to new dataframe (sparse dataframe)
df = pd.SparseDataFrame(te_ary, columns=te.columns_)

# Run algorithm 
frequent_itemsets = apriori(df, min_support=0.10, use_colnames=True)
frequent_itemsets['length'] = frequent_itemsets['itemsets'].apply(lambda x: len(x))
rules = association_rules(frequent_itemsets, metric="confidence", min_threshold=0.3)
```

Below is an example of `dataset`.

```
+----------------------+--+------------------+--+------------------+
|     ReceiptCode      |  | ItemCategoryName |  | StoreCountryName |
+----------------------+--+------------------+--+------------------+
|  0000P70322000031467 |  |  Food            |  |   Denmark        |
|  0000P70322000031867 |  |  Food            |  |   Denmark        |
|  0000P70322000051467 |  |  Interior        |  |   Germany        |
|  0000P70322000087468 |  |  Kitchen         |  |   Switzerland    |
|  0000P70322000031469 |  |  Leisure         |  |   Germany        |
|  0000P70322000031439 |  |  Food            |  |   Switzerland    |
+----------------------+--+------------------+--+------------------+
```

Is it possible to "automatically" create multiple dataframes based on the column `StoreCountryName` and then use it in the algorithm, i.e. use the country-specific dataframe in the analysis and iterate through all countries? I know I can create the dataframes manually, and then just apply the transformations and analysis.

Comment: what about `for store_country_name in dataset['StoreCountryName'].unique():` ... and then pass to your algorithm? Alternatively, you can store them in a dict like `store_country_dict = {}`, `for store_country_name in dataset['StoreCountryName'].unique():`, `store_country_dict[store_country_name] = dataset.loc[dataset['StoreCountryName'] == store_country_name]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can `groupby` and do list comprehension to store the dataframes in a list then iterate over them:

```
g = df.groupby('StoreCountryName')
dfs = [group for _,group in g]

for i in range(len(dfs)):
    dfs[i]['iteration'] = i # do stuff to each frame
    print(f"{dfs[i]} \n")

           ReceiptCode ItemCategoryName StoreCountryName  iteration
0  0000P70322000031467             Food          Denmark          0
1  0000P70322000031867             Food          Denmark          0 

           ReceiptCode ItemCategoryName StoreCountryName  iteration
2  0000P70322000051467         Interior          Germany          1
4  0000P70322000031469          Leisure          Germany          1 

           ReceiptCode ItemCategoryName StoreCountryName  iteration
3  0000P70322000087468          Kitchen      Switzerland          2
5  0000P70322000031439             Food      Switzerland          2
```

Or you can create a function and use `groupby` and `apply`

```
def myFunc(country):
    # do stuff

df.groupby('StoreCountryName').apply(myFunc)
```